# Bulk email sent to group of contacts after new contact added to CiviCRM

Tags: civimail, contacts, email, civirules

We have a couple of sites that offer volunteering directories. External organisations post opportunities and members of the public can view and apply for those opportunities (a massive tangle of webforms and drupal views essentially).

We've been asked for a functionality that if an organisation offers a new opportunity with a given field of activity (eg. buddying/ befriending), and a volunteer has registered with the site expressing an interest in opportunities of that same field of activity then the volunteer(s) get an email notifying them of the new opportunity details.

I was essentially thinking create "field of activity" as a tag list for the opportunity, and a custom data checkbox field for the volunteers. Then create smart groups for volunteers based on the custom data
All contacts, of type volunteer with type of interest "Befriending/Buddying" are added to a Befriending Buddying smart group. When a new opportunity is tagged as Befriending/ Buddying an email goes to the BB smart group.

Had a quick look at configuring a CiviRule, but CiviRules basic settings don't seem to result in Bulk Email Actions

Has anyone configured anything like this in CiviCRM before, or got suggestions of where to start?

Drup 7.69 Civi 5.19.4

Answer (score 1):

Adding here as well

Maybe a scheduled reminder with the activity as the 'trigger' entity and then limit the recipients to your BB smart group would work.

Comment: I had thought of that approach, but is an Scheduled Reminder not just a "transactional" email so if smart group numbers go north of 50 won't send?

I'd be delighted if not.